# Is there a way to tell Google map to zoom out centered on a marker and show a calculated bounding box?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When a visitor clicks a site it shows the StreetView at that location. When they exit the picture the code fetches the nearest two marker coordinates (from a mongodb) and zooms the map out to include the calculated bounding box.

I would like to have it so that the map would remain centered on the marker just visited and  zoom out enough to show the complete bounding box. This would help the user keep track of where they've just been.

[Click the image to calculate the bounding box](http://www.chronoglimpse.com/?id=51f674e4e4b0066cc8197033)

The marker for this image is the one on the very left. As you can see the bounding box is centered.

[image]

I've had a read through but nothing seemed obvious to me. 
Does Google API V3 have a method for this?

```
/****
COLLECT Data from RESTful Service
This code gets the nearest two markers and calculates the zoom to set the map to include them in view.
****/
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng( data.locs.lat, data.locs.lng ));
nearest = {};
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { lat : data.locs.lat,  //the marker you are viewing 
            lng : data.locs.lng},
    async: false,
    url: "php/restful.get.nearest.markers.php",
    success: function (data) {
        nearest = data;  
    }
});
$.each(nearest, function () 
{
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng( this.locs.lat, this.locs.lng ));
});
/****
END COLLECT Data from RESTful Service
****/
map.fitBounds(bounds);  
new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    map: map,
    fillColor: "#000000",
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeWeight: 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the easiest way to do it but it can be a start.

Look at the Google Maps API for [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions). You will see a property called zoom, third from the bottom, which controls your map zoom(obviously).

Then there are two methods getZoom and setZoom in the map's [methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) which can be used to programmatically control the zoom level of the map.

You will have to experiment with these and of course the setCenter should not be big issue.

Experiment and find what the zoom level covers, in terms of distance, calculate what your bounding box covers and set the zoom level and center accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to save sw/ne bounds and set event listener on `bounds_changed`. When bounds change, set center to your marker and check if sw/ne bounds are inside new bounds. If not, zoom out. If visible, clear event listener:

```
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.488986, -10.017925)
    var mapOptions = {
        center: center,
        zoom: 10
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    mapOptions);

    var mainMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // some dummy values for this example
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(53.2, -10));
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(53.8, -9));

    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();

    new google.maps.Rectangle({
        bounds: bounds,
        map: map,
        fillColor: "#000000",
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        strokeWeight: 0
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        map.setCenter(center);

        bounds = map.getBounds();

        if (bounds.contains(sw) && 
            bounds.contains(ne)) {

            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        } else {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```